# Error: "The value for the SHELL variable was not found the /etc/shells file" when running `pkexec`

Tags: command-line, bash, pkexec

On Ubuntu 14.04, I am getting the error "The value for the SHELL variable was not found the /etc/shells file" when running `pkexec` to run a script.

Most likely this error started after I removed the fish shell, that was set as my default shell.

The content of `/etc/shells` is:

> # /etc/shells: valid login shells
>   /bin/sh
>   /bin/dash
>   /bin/bash
>   /bin/rbash

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is this one: `pkexec` is accessing `$SHELL` to determine which shell to use to evaluate the remainder of the command; since you uninstalled fish but didn't do anything else, `$SHELL` still contains `/usr/bin/fish`, but `pkexec` doesn't deem `/usr/bin/fish` as a valid shell, since `/usr/bin/fish` has been removed from `/etc/shells`.

You need to do these two things:

1. Set a new shell for your user, so that the next time the environment is load `$SHELL` will contain a path to a valid shell. E.g. to set Bash as the new shell for your user (replace `user` with your user's username):

   ```
   sudo chsh -s /bin/bash user
   ```
2. Log out / log in to reload the environment so that `$SHELL` contains the path to the new shell for your user.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Without sudo, I received: "You may not change the shell for 'name'." With sudo no error but after loging back in, same  `pkexec` error.

Comment: @J.Doe Right. `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash` changes the shell for root. Do `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash user`, where `user` is your username instead.